# No View is updated after permission turn off and activity Recreated

Tags: android, kotlin, view

i have a screen and I am setting a location on text view after permission granted,it is working fine but when I minimize the app and turn off the location permission and after coming back to that screen system recreates the activity and system asks the permission again when permission granted I am updating the text view and button but its not visible in either of the views however when I debug the text view it has text.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Put app to background
2. Turn off location permission
3. Again move the app to the foreground
4. Activity gets recreated by the system
5. Location updated and text is getting set in the BUtton, TextView and EditText but not visible on the screen

Comment: Can you post the code for where you're setting permissions and the text on the buttons and other views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any fragment on that activity? if yes then wrap your fragment creation code in the following check

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        return
    } else {
        //call fragment

    }
```